# How do i delete a child node of firebase realtime database using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[firebase child node generated by push key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/283t5.png)

Using Javascript , how do I delete a child node generated by push key on firebase realtime database

```
 function createpin() {
  var pin = document.getElementById("createpin").value;
  var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
  let data = {
    Pin: pin,
  }

  firebaseRef.child("Pins/").push(data);
```

the code above is used to add data to the realtime database

Comment: You will need to write code to record the pushed ID, then use that to build a path to the child to delete.  If you don't know the ID, then you can't target it for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database().ref("Path Of Child Node").remove();
```

first you need to get the exact path which you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

***Step 1:**
Import a firebase file configuration*

```
import firebase from "../firebase";
```

***Step2**:
Specify the exact path you want to remove*

```
const db = firebase.ref("Name Table you want to inject");
```

***Step3:**
Create a method to remove firebase data in Real-Time Database*

```
// delete all items
const remove = () => {
  return db.remove();
};

// delete a child node
const remove = (key) => {
  return db.child(key).remove();
};
```

***Step 4:**
Import and use the method into necessary component you need to remove the element*

```
const removeAll = () => {
   NameService.remove().then(() => {})
                       .catch(e => console.log(e))
 }

<button onClick={removeAll}> Remove All </button>
```